# Cumulative Column Sum To Inform Another Column Value in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (pricedata), that contains transaction data for customers. I arrange() the dataframe by TNP for each customer from highest to lowest.  I want to move down from the highest TNP, accumulating the TNP until I reach 60% of the total TNP for the entire column and give all those customers a class = "A". Then continue down the column and give the subsequent customers between 60% and 90% of column total TNP a class = "B", and then the remainder a class= "C".

This is the data:

```
   TNP      Class
 11847.47     C
 11845.76     C
 11840.06     C
 11814.44     C
 11775.24     C
 11766.90     C
```

This is the function I have built to achieve my goal:

```
FUN.sthp.1 <- function(TNP) { 
  #The dataframe must be ordered by TNP for this cumsum function to work
  Acut<-(.6*sum(pricedata$TNP))
  Bcut<-(.9*sum(pricedata$TNP))
  Ccut<-(1*sum(pricedata$TNP))

  Summary.DF<- pricedata[pricedata$TNP>=TNP,]
  total<-sum(Summary.DF$TNP)

  Class<-ifelse(total<=Acut, "A", 
              ifelse(total<=Bcut & total>Acut, "B",
                     "C"))
  return(Class)
}
```

I then call this function using mapply() and feed the TNP.

Is there a function, or a feature within a function, that will achieve the same thing without all the typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to get the cumulative sum. Divide this by the total `sum`. Then you can assign levels using `cut`. There are options to deal with the margins (what happens at 60% etc.) you can see the help file using `?cut`

```
"TNP      Class
11847.47     C
11845.76     C
11840.06     C
11814.44     C
11775.24     C
11766.90     C" -> myDat
out <- read.table(text = myDat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
cut(cumsum(out$TNP)/sum(out$TNP), breaks =c(0,60,90,100)/100, labels = LETTERS[1:3])
[1] A A A B B C
```